# Discord API - UserID Request in PHP

Tags: php, api, discord

I am currently attempting to query the user information for any given discord account. Its pretty simple, I give the website a Discord User ID and it outputs that specific users account information.

I believe my issue is related directly to how discord authorizes their bots and after about an hour of google searching I figured it would be better to ask here.

Any help much appreciated!

**Current Code:**

```
$IDURL = "https://discord.com/api/v8/users/" . $UserID;
$CurlInitID = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array( $CurlInitID, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $IDURL,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Authorization: Bot *private key removed*"
    ]
]);

$Return = curl_exec($CurlInitID);
curl_close($CurlInitID);

die($Return);
```

**Return From Website:**

`{"message": "405: Method Not Allowed", "code": 0}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is still not solved here is the solution:

```
<?php
    
    $discordId = "YourDiscordID";
    $token = "YourToken";
    $url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/users/{$discordId}";
    
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Authorization: Bot {$token}\r\n",
            'method'  => 'GET',
        ),
    );
    
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    if ($response === false) {
        die('Error fetching data from Discord API');
    }
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $response;
    
?>
```

If you want to be able to retrieve the data you add this for example:

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
if ($data === null) {
    die('Error decoding JSON data');
}
```

So you can use the elements by retrieving them like this:

```
$discordAvatar = $data['avatar'];
$discordUsername = $data['username'];
$discordDiscriminator = $data['discriminator'];
$discordId = $data['id'];
```